# How to encrypt file names and folder names in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

I have to encrypt file names and folder names. The challenge is that the encrypted name string can have invalid characters for file name if I use AES 256 encryption. Do you have any suggestions how to handle this? Is this the right way to do file name encryption?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Base64 encode the encrypted string?

Comment: We want to use custom encryption for all the content in the app. So the app's data will be encrypted even if device is not pin code locked or jail broken.

Comment: @LieRyan Base64? As encryption?

Comment: Encrypt the name, then convert that to a base 64 encoding. Use the resulting encoded string as the name. Use A-Z,a-z,0-9, and two other legal characters for your base 64 algorithm.

Comment: :D why is this question getting minus points. I believe it is a valid question.

Comment: @H2CO3 He said to use base 64 on the encrypted string, not to use base 64 as the form of encryption.

Comment: How is a filename part of your app's data? The data is in the file, not the filename itself.

Comment: @H2CO3: Base64 after AES. Base64 is just to transliterate all the byte patterns produced by AES into characters that are valid for filename.

Comment: @JimPuls - File and folder names are also confidential in our app.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted without reason?  It is a valid question (though lacking in details -- *which* files and folders, in particular).

Comment: I would say bbum's second suggestion -- replace your names with something else.  If you think it's necessary you can keep the name to whatever translation in a SqlCipher database.

Comment: It's probably getting downvoted mostly because the obvious answer -- use Base64 -- is, well, obvious.  It's something that anyone working with encryption should be able to come up with in their sleep.

Comment: @HotLicks That really isn't true;  I know a number of developers that wouldn't have the first clue about Base64 because they haven't done work with either HTTP or MIME encodings, nor would I expect that every dev that knows about Base64 would assume that it yields an ASCII encoding.   Assuming newcomers have knowledge that those of us with decades of experience find second nature, and abusing them for their supposed ignorance, is a fantastic dis-incentive to learning.  Through patience knowledge is transferred.

Comment: My statement was that anyone *working with encryption* should know about Base64.  Working with encryption assumes you've progressed beyond "newcomer" level.  (FWIW, I *did not* downvote the question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer varies depending on how far you want to take this;   the suggesting of encrypting the file names and then running the encrypted result through a base64 encoder is a solid suggestion.

Alternatively, you might consider simply using UUIDs for all filenames and then have an (encrypted) data file that maps between UUID and what the file contains in the context of your application.

You won't be able to control the names given to system generated files;  cache entries, defaults, etc...

Overall, encrypting the filenames is a bit futile.  If the contents are encrypted, the names don't really matter and you are free to choose names that are meaningful while remaining confidential (i.e. code names).    If the contents aren't encrypted, then vague / meaningless filenames aren't much good anyway.

Comment: Thanks bbum. In our case we will be encrypting both content and file names.